# Separate comma delimited cells to new rows with shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bioinformatics

I have a table with comma delimited columns and I want to separate the comma delimited values in my specified column to new rows. For example, the given table is

```
Name    Start   Name2

A   1,2 X,a

B   5   Y,b

C   6,7,8   Z,c
```

And I need to separate the comma delimited values in column 2 to get the table below

```
Name    Start   Name2

A   1   X,a

A   2   X,a

B   5   Y,b

C   6   Z,c

C   7   Z,c

C   8   Z,c
```

I am wondering if there is any solution with shell script, so that I can create a workflow pipe.

Note: the original table may contain more than 3 columns.

Comment: [When you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) solving this yourself, what problems did you run into? And why Bash?

Comment: I hope to pipe the output into other commands, it will save some time compared with doing it in R and then go back.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format of your input and output does not change:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ ,]"} {print $1, $2, $NF; print $1, $3, $NF}' input_file
```

**Input**:

`input_file`:

```
A 1,2 X    
B 5,6 Y
```

**Output**:

```
A 1 X
A 2 X
B 5 Y
B 6 Y
```

**Explanation**:

- `awk`: invoke `awk`, a tool for manipulating lines (records) and fields
- `'...'`: content enclosed by single-quotes are supplied to `awk` as instructions
- `'BEGIN{FS="[ ,]"}`: before reading any lines, tell awk to use both space and comma as delimiters; FS stands for Field Separator.
- `{print $1, $2, $NF; print $1, $3, $NF}`: For each input line read, print the 1st, 2nd and last field on one line, and then print the 1st, 3rd, and last field on the next line. NF stands for Number of Fields, so `$NF` is the last field.
- `input_file`: supply the name of the input file to awk as an argument.

---

In response to updated input format:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ ,]"} {print $1, $2, $4","$5; print $1, $3, $4","$5}' input_file
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I specify the column that contains comma delimited values? And the table may contain more than 3 columns.

Comment: @Runner how do you mean? could you give some use cases as an edit in your original question? (specific examples are good, because it can help define corner cases for your problem)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Now I have modified my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My bad. I still did not provide a good example. I modified the question again.

Answer (score 0):

After Runner's modification of the original question another approach might look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Usage $0 <file> <column>
#

FILE="${1}"

COL="${2}"

# tokens separated by linebreaks
IFS="
"

for LINE in `cat ${FILE}`; do
    # get number of columns
    COLS="`echo ${LINE} | awk '{print NF}'`"

    # get actual field by COL, this contains the keys to be splitted into individual lines
    # replace comma with newline to "reuse" newline field separator in IFS
    KEYS="`echo ${LINE} | cut -d' ' -f${COL}-${COL} | tr ',' '\n'`"

    COLB=$(( ${COL} - 1 ))
    COLA=$(( ${COL} + 1 ))

    # get text from columns before and after actual field
    if [ ${COLB} -gt 0 ]; then
            BEFORE="`echo ${LINE} | cut -d' ' -f1-${COLB}` "
    else
            BEFORE=""
    fi

    AFTER=" `echo ${LINE} | cut -d' ' -f${COLA}-`"

    # echo "-A: $COLA ($AFTER) | B: $COLB ($BEFORE)-"

    # iterate keys and re-build original line
    for KEY in ${KEYS}; do
            echo "${BEFORE}${KEY}${AFTER}"
    done
done
```

With this shell file you might do what you want. This will split column 2 into multiple lines.

```
./script.sh input.txt 2
```

If you'd like to pass inputs though standard input using pipes (e.g. to split multiple columns in one go) you could change the 6. line to:

```
if [ "${1}" == "-" ]; then
    FILE="/dev/stdin"
else 
    FILE="${1}"
fi
```

And run it this way:

```
./script.sh input.txt 1 | ./script.sh - 2 | ./script.sh - 3
```

**Note** that cut is very sensitiv about the field separators. Soif the line starts with a space character, column 1 would be "" (empty). If the fields were separated by amixture of spaces and tabs this script would have other issues too. In this case (as explained above) filtering the input resource (so that fields are only separated by one space character) should do it. If this is not possible or the data in each column contains space characters too, the script might get more complicated.